# Gibbs free energy of phosphorus pentachloride decomposition reaction

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium, free-energy

> The equilibrium constant at $\pu{227 °C}$ for the equation
>
> $$\ce{PCl5(g) <=> PCl3(g) + Cl2(g)}$$
>
> is $K_p = \pu{4.50E3 bar}.$ Calculate the value of $Δ_\mathrm{rxn}G^\circ$ at  $\pu{227 °C}$.
>
> With the temperature at $\pu{227 °C}$ and the partial pressures of the gases of  $p(\ce{PCl3}) = \pu{0.286 bar},$ $p(\ce{Cl2}) = \pu{0.713 bar},$ and $p(\ce{PCl5}) = \pu{3.06E-6 bar},$ calculate the value of $Δ_\mathrm{rxn}G.$

I calculated $Δ_\mathrm{rxn}G^\circ$ to be $\pu{-34.97 kJ mol-1}.$ Wouldn't it just be

$$Δ_\mathrm{rxn}G^\circ = -\pu{0.0083145 kJ mol-1 K-1} × \pu{500 K} × \ln(\pu{4.5E3})?$$

For the second part of the question I got $\pu{11.20 kJ mol-1},$ but apparently this is also wrong, no doubt because I got the first part wrong.

Would someone care to explain to me?

Comment: What makes you think the first answer is wrong?

Comment: The website we submit the answer to (Sapling) claims it is wrong.

Comment: I have no idea what Sapling is, but probably they expect another format, number of sig figs or different units? Do they provide an answer?

Comment: It's like a HW platform. I've tried different sig figs and units are already provided. They don't provide an answer unless you either solve it correctly or press "Give Up".

Comment: So I ended up pressing "Give Up". Apparently it wanted only 1 Sig Fig, but no where in the question did it ask for it.

Comment: Well, that's one of the reasons I don't like online tests. Good job on your side though:)